# single link link swap node debacle

Tags: c, linked-list

Just finished studying single linked list, and started to do exercises.

For this one, I'm trying to make the program swap two adjacent nodes. when I'm not choosing the head or the last node it's swapping correctly, my problem is when I'm trying to swap the head. it swapped with the next node(which is right), but the next node seems to not go to the head.

Below is the whole code but I think the only concern here is the VOID SWAP procedure. JUST POSTED the whole code, in case, someone ask for the whole code.

```
typedef struct node{
    char element [4];
    struct node * next;
}nodeType;

nodeType * push(nodeType *early){
    nodeType *nptr = (nodeType*)malloc(sizeof(nodeType)) ;
    printf("Enter three character long word: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nptr->element);

    if(early==NULL){
        nptr->next = NULL;
    }else{
        nptr->next = early;
    }
    return nptr;
}

nodeType* searchNode(nodeType*startNode){
    ///get user input
    char input[4];
    int match;
    nodeType * wnptr = NULL;

    printf("Enter the word to swap: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(input);

    ///search for the word
    while(startNode!=NULL){
        if (strcmp(input, startNode->element)==0){
            if(startNode->next == NULL){
                printf("Nothing to swap with.\n");
                match = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                wnptr = startNode;
                match = 1;
                break;
            }
         } else {
            wnptr = NULL;
            match = 0;
            startNode = startNode->next;
        }
    }

    if (match == 0){
        printf("Match not found\n");
    }
    return wnptr;
}

nodeType * searchPrev(nodeType*startNode, nodeType*searchedNode){
    nodeType * prevptr = NULL;

    while(startNode!=NULL){
        if (startNode->next==searchedNode){
            prevptr = startNode;
            break;
        } else if (startNode->next!=searchedNode){
            prevptr = NULL;
            startNode = startNode->next;
        }
    }
    return prevptr;
}

void swap(nodeType*newhead ,nodeType*prev, nodeType*searchedNode){
    if(prev == NULL){
        nodeType*adjNode = searchedNode->next;
        searchedNode->next=adjNode->next;
        adjNode->next = searchedNode;
    } else {
        nodeType*adjNode = searchedNode->next;
        prev->next = adjNode;
        searchedNode->next=adjNode->next;
        adjNode->next = searchedNode;
    }
}

void printList(nodeType*start){

    nodeType*currentNode = start;

    while(currentNode!=NULL){
        printf("%s ", currentNode->element);

        currentNode=currentNode->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void cleanUp (nodeType*start){

    nodeType*currentNode = start;
    nodeType*holdadd = NULL;

    while(currentNode!=NULL){
        holdadd = currentNode->next;
        free(currentNode);
        currentNode=holdadd;
    }
}
int main(){

char command[7];
char temp[4];
nodeType *head = NULL;
nodeType *swaptr = NULL;
nodeType *preptr = NULL;


    while(printf("Type command to perform:\npush\nswap\nprint\nexit\nCommand: ")){
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", command);

        if(strcmp(command, "exit")==0){
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(command, "push")==0){
                head = push(head);
        }

        if (strcmp(command, "swap")==0){
                swaptr = searchNode(head);
                preptr = searchPrev(head, swaptr);
                swap(head, preptr, swaptr);
        }


        if (strcmp(command, "print")==0){
            printList(head);
            printf("%u", head);
        }

    }
    cleanUp(head);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void swap(nodeType*newhead ,nodeType*prev, nodeType*searchedNode){
    if(prev == NULL){
        nodeType*adjNode = searchedNode->next;
        searchedNode->next=adjNode->next;
        adjNode->next = searchedNode;
        newhead= adjNode;
    } else {
        nodeType*adjNode = searchedNode->next;
        prev->next = adjNode;
        searchedNode->next=adjNode->next;
        adjNode->next = searchedNode;
       }
   }
```

Comment: The only thing you are missing is reassigning of the head pointer to the newly swapped node.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more detailed: The value of head is changed inside swap() but when the function call returns, the value of head remains the same. So, you would have to pass pointer to pointer to swap for the new value of head to persist. Following are the changes:


`void swap(nodeType**newhead ,nodeType*prev, nodeType*searchedNode)`

`*newhead=adjNode;`


and while calling swap, change to :`swap(&head, preptr, swaptr);`